# Buildozer Error Kivy Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "myapp"

Tags: android, python, ios, kivy, buildozer

im trying to create an apk from a simple project, i have created .spec with init but then when i try to use:

```
buildozer -v android debug
```

it gives me this error:

```
building 'jnius' extension
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer  
--sysroot /home/painkiller/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c 
platforms/android-19/arch-arm -DNDEBUG -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-
pointer --sysroot /home/painkiller/.buildozer/android/platform/android-
ndk-r9c/platforms/android-19/arch-arm -fPIC -I/home/painkiller/Scrivania
/2048-master/2048_Doge/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
/build/python-install/include/python2.7 -c jnius/jnius.c -o  
build/temp.linux-
x86_64-2.7/jnius/jnius.o

arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error: jnius/jnius.c: No such file or directory
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
error: command 'arm-linux-androideabi-gcc' failed with exit status 1
# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "myapp"
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```